# N-gram based dataset Structure for Text Classification in R

Tags: r, classification, data-mining, text-classification, n-gram

I want to generate n-grams from a set of user generated sentiments. All statements are placed in a single column in my dataset.

I have been around packages `quanteda`,  `tokenizers` and `tm` for most of my text processing and text mining tasks.

Now my question would be, how do I structure my dataset to be able to use n-grams as part of the features used in learning the model from. Are the tokens placed in separate columns? Or tokens are placed in 1 column and just let classification tasks do their thing?

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data? Try using the `dput` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/dput) and copy-pasting the output to share. Depending on your data, you may just want to first take only a few rows using `head` and then `dput` that.

Comment: Hi! Let's say for instance my dataset is a column for tweets from Twitter.

Comment: Sorry, beigel, I'm quite new to stackoverflow. When I used `dput` and `head` to return my first few rows, it still returned everything from my dataset.

Comment: I'll give you some example code, if I wanted to `dput` the first few rows of the built-in `mtcars` dataset, I'd run `dput(head(mtcars))`

Comment: I did that for my dataset but still posted all rows. I'd also like to add an additional question. How do I use n-grams as features for training my model? @beigel